# Can not find navigation drawer layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

When building my application I selected the template with the navigation drawer. Now however I can't access the drawer to edit from the design tab in android studio. 
[Image of Template I chose for refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6UIx.png)

Is their something in I need to do in the XML (below) to make it view able again?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="56dp"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:visibility="visible">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/inactiveButton"
        android:layout_width="346dp"
        android:layout_height="346dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_pressed" />
```

EDIT: [squished view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GAh8.png)

Comment: You can find the Drawer in res/menu/activity_main_drawer.xml

Comment: Thanks this worked. However I still can't edit the design it's squished I'll post a picture above.

Comment: I always prefer designing my layout in text mode, I'm not very experienced in Design View

Comment: Ok I'll try that maybe if I edit the text mode it will come into view